# Laravel get relation data

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the relation data but I get `Trying to get property 'district_name' of non-object` error. I'm Just learning laravel.

[image]

Here is my models:

**LibSchool**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LibSchool extends Model
{
    function getAllSchool()
    {
        return LibSchool::all();
    }

    public function district()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LibDistrict');
    }
}
```

**LibDistrict**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\LibSchool;

class LibDistrict extends Model
{
    public function schools()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LibSchool');
    }
}
```

**Tables**

[image]
[image]

**CONTROLLER**

```
class SchoolController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $q = Input::get('q');
        if ($q != "") {
            $schools = LibSchool::where('school_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                        ->with('district')
                        ->orWhere('school_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                        ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                        ->orWhere('school_head', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                        ->orWhere('level', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                        ->orderBy('school_name', 'asc')
                        ->paginate(15)->appends('q', $q);
        } else {
            $schools = LibSchool::with('district')
                                ->orderBy('school_name', 'asc')
                                ->paginate(15);
        }
        return view('schools.index')->with('data', ['schools' => $schools, 'q' => $q]);
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>School ID</th>
        <th>School NAME</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>School Head</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Division</th>
        <th>District</th>
    </tr>
    @if($data['schools']->total() > 0)
    @foreach($data['schools'] as $school)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$school->school_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$school->school_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$school->address}}</td>
        <td>{{$school->school_head}}</td>
        <td>{{$school->level}}</td>
        <td>{{$school->district->district_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    @else
    <td colspan="7" class="text-danger">No records</td>
    @endif
</table>
{{$data['schools']->links()}}
```

Comment: try this `<td>{{$school->district()->district_name}}</td>`

Comment: it says `null`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your given code is that you have used

```
public function district()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\LibDistrict');
}
```

which assumes that you have `libdistrict_id` as foreign key in `district` table. But looking at your table it seems that you have assigned it as `lib_district_id`. So, now you have to explicitly put the proper column name like follows:

```
public function district()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\LibDistrict', 'lib_district_id', 'id');
}
```

Note: It's always better to use the naming convention provided by laravel. That way our code can be much less and clean.

Hope this helps!! Have fun coding!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you write `{{ dd($school->district) }}` and check the result in the index page before

```
<td>{{$school->school_id}}</td>
```

Comment: It says `null`. Why is it null?

Comment: As no relation with this class i mean the foreign key may not added
,make the code like that
 LibSchool::->with('district')->where('school_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
Can you take screenshot from your database, plz?

Comment: Are you put protected $fillable  in your  model class?

Comment: what do you mean by screenshot of my database? I already pasted it above. And I did not put `protected $fillable` in class model.

Comment: $Fillable Property: specifies which attributes in the table should be *mass-assignable.
like
protected $fillable=['div_id','district_name']
and specify the foreign key 
public function district()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LibDistrict','lib_district_id');
    }
-- I mean screenshot of data

Comment: Put the foreign key as i wrote in the past comment in your relation district

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

```
{{ $school->district ? $school->district->district_name : 'N/A' }}
```

By this, if your school district exists then it will print district name otherwise it will show `N/A`.

Comment: It says NA to all. I will add screen shot of sample record from database.

Comment: @beginner it means your relationship is not correct. can you tell me that in your `LibSchools` table, `lib_district_id` field has ids? and also those ids should be present in your `lib_districts` table. Please confirm.